# Dynamically changing a JComboBox Cell Editor

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox, tablecelleditor

The only sample I have is rather large so I am hoping to post this more as a general question to get an understanding of internal flow.

JTable has two JComboBoxes as Cell Editors for two different columns. 
The select list within JComboBox2 will depend on the what is selected from JComboBox1.

This works for the most part. 
When an item is selected from JComboBox1 the list dynamically changes behind the scene for JComboBox2. 
The problem is the data is the cell itself doesn't change until I explicitly click on the JComboBox2 cell.

If in the code where I dynamically change the data for JComboBox2 I also explicitly change the cell data via the following call it works fine.

```
myTable.getModel().setValueAt(comboBox2.getModel().getElementAt(0), row, col);
```

Is this the expected process that both the ComboBox and Table models be updated?
Is there a way to simply update the ComboBox2 and have it automatically update what is seen in the JTable?

Comment: I would imagine, when `setValueAt` is called for the first column, you would verify the value for the second column as well, changing it as required

Comment: How exactly are you changing the data for combo box 2? I just wrote a small test program that calls comboBox2.setModel(updated/new combo box model) when I select something in box 1, and the data in box 2 changes from its current selection to the first item in the new combo box model.

Comment: That is essentially what I am doing. The data in ComboBox2 changes as expected, but if you don't click the cell to view the content of ComboBox2 the actual cell data still retains its previous value. Its only after cell 2 is clicked will it replace the data. I had to include the setValueAt call in order to change the data in the cell just in case the person never decides to click ComboBox2. I am wondering if also having a CellRenderer and CellEditor may require having the setValueAt call. I will see about scaling down a sample to something manageable.